# How to limit ParamArray Bounds In VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, function, paramarray

I was working on a function that accepts ParamArrays. But it should have at least one element and the maximum of 5 elements. I tried defining array bounds but got an error `Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers`.

So how can I do this?

Comment: This cannot be enforced at compile-time, you'll have to check at runtime and throw an exception when you're not happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the context of your question, I would suggest doing what you can to make the function signature honor the contract you are requiring. For instance:

```
Public Sub Grover (cheese1 as Cheese, Optional cheese2 as Cheese = Nothing, Optional cheese3 as Cheese = Nothing, Optional cheese4 as Cheese = Nothing, Optional cheese5 as Cheese = Nothing)
    If cheese1 Is Nothing Then
        'throw
    End If

    For Each cheese in {cheese1, cheese2, cheese3, cheese4, cheese5}
        If cheese IsNot Nothing Then
            cheese.Snozzle()
        End If

        'or, in VB14 (as of Visual Studio 2015)
        cheese?.Snozzle()
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I do this?

You can’t. Not statically at least. The only thing you can do is check inside the function and throw an exception (e.g. an [`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) when the wrong number of arguments is encountered.

In terms of API design this strikes me as weird, however. I don’t think a `ParamArray` is the best solution in your case, precisely because you seem to have restrictions which are not well reflected by a `ParamArray`.

Comment: Is there a way to throw exceptions when editing the code? like when we miss a non optional argument.

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian Unfortunately I do not understand that question.

Comment: when you are using a function, if you miss an argument, it will underlines the function and the error is about number of arguments and it prevents compiling. How can I do this?

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian You can’t. This is what “you can’t do this statically” means. The most you could do would be to write a rule plugin for a static analysis tool and annotate the function arguments with a custom attribute. However, this is a lot (and I mean *a lot*) of effort for next to no benefit. I strongly suggest solving this differently. As I’ve said, a `ParamArray` is probably not the correct solution here.